# Telling manager my ambitions

Tags: manager

I'm a 25 year old working in a large bank. My manager is in her 40s and is one level above me in terms of seniority.

A lot of my work is planned by her and I come in at the end to do the "grunt work". I want to explain to her that I am fairly ambitious and my goal is to progress to a level that is two levels above where she is and three levels above where I am currently.

I want to ask her to give me a problem, rather than a plan and let me figure out how to solve it rather than being told what I need to do. I.e. delegate to me much earlier in the project and let me deliver it with less supervision.

I know for sure I would not be able to do it all without her help, but I'd prefer to go to her when I get stuck for coaching so that I'm at least learning and growing.

Is this a reasonable thing to suggest? How should I approach it?

Answer (score 3):

> A lot of my work is planned by her and I come in at the end to do the
> "grunt work". I want to explain to her that I am fairly ambitious and
> my goal is to progress to a level that is two levels above where she
> is and three levels above where I am currently.

There is really no need to say you want to go above her (unless you really have a good relationship with her, which you do not seem to have). You can just say that you're ambitious and that you'd like to try working with less direct supervision.

With that said, if you want to rise above her rank, you may need to jump around from employer to employer. Staying too long at a company is rarely good for a career. Also, staying too long under a micromanager may not be good for your career either.

> I want to ask her to give me a problem, rather than a plan and let me figure out how to solve it rather than being told what I need to do. I.e. **delegate to me much earlier in the project** and let me deliver it with less supervision.

How about you anticipate what the next problem is going to be instead of just waiting until she assigns you one, then, you can show off your initiative.

Comment: This is a related comment for the author of the question.  In order to get a level above your direct supervisor, you must first reach her level, so it would be appropriate to ask them for career advice to achieve that specific goal.  In my opinion you should leave out ultimate goal of being what would basically be their supervisor.  You might have to reach for other mentors also in order to achieve your goal.  This includes going to their supervisor and asking them to be a mentor.  You might have to create an entire network (multiple companies) of mentors in order to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a reasonable thing to suggest?

No it isn't. It's the same as asking her to give you part of her role without the responsibility. She will still be responsible for the outcomes.

The grunt work as you call it is normal, attempting to skip it is not seen as ambition by many. Because it's important to fully understand and it's important in itself as part of a bigger picture.

Comment: I'm not attempting to skip the grunt work, I'm suggesting I do more of the planning in addition to the work I'm already doing.

Comment: yeah, during your time designated for grunting, so less time for that and work someone else is responsible for. You need to look from the other perspective, there is no benefit except to you but more work and a myriad of potential issues that you won't ultimately be accountable for.

Comment: @Milo: It's not hard to interpret your words as meaning "I want to call the shots", even if that's inaccurate or only partially true. Be very aware of this when you speak. Especially in conjunction with intending to tell someone you intend to surpass them, which further implies (or can be interpreted to mean) you think that you're better than them.

Answer (score 1):

> A lot of my work is planned by her and I come in at the end to do the "grunt work". I want to explain to her that I am fairly ambitious and my goal is to progress to a level that is two levels above where she is and three levels above where I am currently.

There are several ways your manager might look at this situation based on the experiences she might have.

1. She might see your ambition and want to lay out the groundwork for you to get there.
2. She might just ignore it. Either tell you that it's possible or perhaps outright say there's no chance for you.
3. She might see you as a potential problem right now. She might combine this with #2 and try to use you just a tad bit longer. But generally, when someone says they want to go for manager and display no skillset to that, they know ultimately you're going to leave when your expectations aren't met.

> Is this a reasonable thing to suggest? How should I approach it?

Rather than say your goal is to go above her, maybe you can have something more specific that she can help you with. Perhaps asking her if you could be tasked with taking a lead on some project. As you said you want to ask her for you to solve a "problem" but perhaps you can instead ask her you want to supervise a team and wish to gain experience that route. Perhaps she can assist you with that and see what sort of things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this would not be too bright.  Right now your boss is in a place where she's set up in the org chart as your *mentor*.  If you push this agenda out in the open, she's going to reframe you as a *competitor*.  You may create a bias against yourself because you'll be instantly perceived as someone who wants to climb the corporate ladder without putting in the work.  Your boss will be rightfully guarded against giving you contact with others who you can influence *against* her interests.  And your performance reviews are likely to suffer.

Do you really think this is still a great idea?

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple answers on how this would be a bad idea, but I want to approach this from a different angle.

Companies where I've worked (Western Europe) always had personal growth in mind, and this was one of the focus point of my meetings with the people in my team. Where do they want to grow? What skills do they want to learn? What are their ambitions?

If you go to talk to your manager about growth, make sure you come prepared though. Why would you be good at this? How did you earn her trust to give you these responsibilities? What will you do if you fail? How will you try to prevent failure? Do you need extra training for this? Don't go in there and state blankly that you want to grow. Show up with a plan!

The fact that you show ambition is good, and a competent manager should appreciate that and support you in that growth. Make sure to take this one step at a time. Don't tell her that you want to be above her in five years, but talk about this first step specifically. Giving you a bit more responsibilities will allow you to grow, and could potentially free up time from your manager. Do make sure that your grunt work doesn't suffer, since that's your core responsibility and that should be your priority!

If your manager blocks you from growing, you will not be able to develop yourself in your career. Consider what that means for your future, and whether you want to work for this company much longer.